# one-to-many with hibernate 4.2.2

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the below entities.

```
Order{

@Id
 private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="order_id_fk", updatable = false)
private List<OrderRelease> orderReleases;

}
```

and my manager code looks like this. create methods have @Transactional

```
OrderResponse response = super.create(entry);
if(orderReleases !=null){  
    for(OrderReleaseEntry releaseEntry: orderReleases){  
         releaseEntry.setOrderId(response.getData().get(0).getId());  
             orderReleaseManager.create(releaseEntry);
    }
}
```

This piece of code has been working fine with hibernate 3.6.0.Final.. but when i migrate to hibernate 4.2.2.Final, this starts throwing Foreign key violation exception

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myntra_oms`.`order_release`, CONSTRAINT `FK36452816EEB04872` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id_fk`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`))

I am using spring for transaction management, i have jpa and hibernate as orm.

Comment: Show us the code of OrderRelease, and the code which actually creates the order release, adds it to the order, and throws the exception.

Comment: orderReleaseManager.create() in turn calls dao.create.. dao has  entityManager.persist(entity);

Comment: Looking at the exception it seems there is no order with a particular id. Are you sure your OrderResponse object only contains valid order id's?